# Li-ion battery choose question

Tags: power-supply, power, batteries, battery-charging

I am new to this forum and I hope you can help me with this.
I want to build a small circuit that will have: an ATXMEGA ucontroler that uses all of its 5 USART and one bluetooth module. This circuit must power up another 4(sensors) circuits with an atmega8 each. I suppose I need a voltage over 5V for the sensors so one 3.7 V li-ion will not do the trick.
Can you suggest me what battery to use? Do I need more batteries in series to power up my devices? I want an autonomy of around 1,2(longer is better)  with recharge capability.
My circuit neets to be very small, so I want small bateries preferably to fir 3cm x 3 cm board.

I found this small one but can you suggest others and some tips for how much power. 
https://www.sparkfun.com/products/731

The components presented above are the only things on the cip. I will give more details: basically I will have 4 sensors diven by 4 uC atmega88 that comunicates over UART with the main board. The main board uses these 4 UART+ another one for bluetooth.(In the future I would like to add and inductive charging so maybe will be some more circuits,for now I will use micro USB charging method) The main board also has an pasive nfc tag but that is not power up(obviously) .

Comment: You forgot to give your unit of time. And there are ways of getting 5V from Li-ion cells.

Comment: I do not understand. What limit of time?

Comment: what batteries have you researched that might fit the space? Have you found any or are you hoping for a recommendation?

Comment: Hello, I want some suggestions about how much power do I need. For the size i have a board of 3 x 3cm maybe 4 cm but not bigger, so I need some suggestion using rechargeable coins battery or such things..I am not very good at power consuption.

Comment: It sounds like you really have 2 questions. 1) How much power are your components going to consume.  2) What battery has enough power to run your components while being small enough to fit on your board. I am not familiar enough with those components to estimate your power requirements, but that battery that you provided a link to does not have a lot of power in it.

Comment: Charging Li-ion or Li-Po batteries isn't trivial. You will need an ic to handle the charging. Lithiums store a good amount of power, and will release it all at once (explosion) if they're not charged correctly... Also, I don't think you can charge two in series. So, best to use just one battery, and use a boost converter to get the higher voltage.

Comment: Yes, charging of lithium batteries does require an IC, but you can charge 2 lithium batteries in series, but after many charges the cells will likely become unbalanced.  This means that the two batteries will have slightly different voltages that will slowly get worse with subsequent charges - not a good thing.  You can get a charger that balance charges the batteries - this will solve the problem, or you can get a PCB to attach to the batteries that will balance them as they charge and protect them from over discharge as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Choosing the right battery for your circuit is not a simple task. You don't give much details of your component's power consumptions neither your autonomy requirements, but I will tell you how to proceed so you can choose the right battery.

First of all you need to choose the proper voltage. Since your sensors work at 5V, a single cell is not enough. You need to go for a 2S pack (2 cells in series). This will give you 7.4 nominal voltage (you will probably need a voltage regulator to drop to 5v)

It is important to know how much current will your circuit drawn at maximum. For this you need to look into the datasheet for the sensors and the microcontrollers consumptions. Will all the components of the circuit be working at the same time? If not it's not necessary to sum all the consumptions together, just make and estimation.

Once you know your current consumption, there are two main things you need to take into account:

- **Discharge Rate:** You can never exceed the discharge rate of your Li-ion battery. Discharge rate is measured in C-rate. C refers to the battery capacity. For the battery you propose, 2C rate means that the discharge current can not be higher than two times the battery capacity. It is a 110mAh battery so you can never never exceed 220mA.
- **Capacity:** You need to make sure that you capacity meets your autonomy requirements. This is simple to calculate, once you have your power consumption. Let's say your consumption is 200mA and you need an autonomy of 1.2 hours. You will need a capacity of 100mA*1.2h = 120mAh